# Optimize LINQ query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql, query-optimization

I have a report that shows orders made to a determined merchant, and it was working fine until I needed to add a filter for payment status.

This is how I build the query, filter by filter:

```
var queryOrder = context.Orders.Select(m=>m);

if (viewModel.InitialDate.HasValue)
    queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(m => m.CreatedDate.Date >= viewModel.InitialDate.Value);

(...) /* continues building the query, filter by filter */


if (viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus != null)
    queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(m => viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Contains(m.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single().ToString()));

queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(m => m.MerchantId == merchantId);
```

When I run `queryOrder`, even if it's only a `queryOrder.Count()`, it takes over 1 minute to execute. Using SQL Server's profiling tool, I extracted the generated query as this:

```
SELECT [t0].[Id], [t0].[CustomerId], [t0].[MerchantId], [t0].[OrderNumber], [t0].[Amount], [t0].[SoftDescriptor], [t0].[ShippingMethod], [t0].[ShippingPrice], [t0].[IpAddress], [t0].[SellerComment], [t0].[CreatedDate]
FROM [dbo].[Order] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[MerchantId] = @p0) 
AND ((CONVERT(NVarChar,(
       SELECT [t1].[PaymentStatusId]
       FROM [dbo].[Payment] AS [t1]
       WHERE [t1].[OrderId] = [t0].[Id]
    ))) IN (@p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8))
```

the @p0 parameter is a Guid for merchantId, and the @p1 thru @p8 are numeral strings `"1"` thru `"8"`, representing the paymentStatusId's.

If I skip the line:

```
if (viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus != null)
    queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(m => viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Contains(m.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single().ToString()));
```

The query runs in under 1 second. But when I use it, the performance hits the floor. Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: are you saying the generated sql is running faster?

Comment: and is this entity framework or linq to sql?

Comment: no, the generated sql runs slow even on the sql management studio. It's linq to sql

Comment: queryOrder.Where(m => viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Contains(m.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single().ToString()));

What is this line of code trying to do? The ToString() is probably a big part of the bottleneck since it does a CONVERT on all the values in your query, can you do it in another way? and maybe skip Single and use First()?

Answer (score 0):

All your queries are deferred and this is both the good/bad part of linq. Try to split the queries and use some in-memory results. 
Try removing the first query (doesn't make much sense really, you're returning the same collection) and amend the second query to be like this and see if it makes any difference.

```
var clause = context.Orders.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single().ToString();
if (viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus != null)
    var queryOrder = context.Orders.queryOrder.Where(m => viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Contains(clause));
```

Comment: the first query isn't as bad as you seem to think.  The identity select isn't going to really cause any problems (particularly on an iqueryable, in which the query provider will essentially realize it's a no-op.  What he's really doing is ensuring `queryOrder` is typed as an `IQueryable` rather than the underlying collection type.  This could be better served by just a call to `AsQueryable`, which would do the same thing, but convey the meaning somewhat better.  The other option is to not use `var` and instead manually type out the variable to be an `IQueryable`.

Comment: True, it's just that it looks redundant as DbSet already implement IQueryable. Btw I think the difference will be in stripping out the clause of Contains and make it an in-memory result.

Answer (score 0):

I've annotated the problem snippet:

```
if (viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus != null) {

    // Give me only orders from queryOrder where...
    queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(

        // ...my viewModel's SelectedPaymentStatus collection...
        m => viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Contains(

                 // ...contains the order's payment's PaymentStatusId...
                 m.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single()

                                          // ... represented as a string?!
                                         .ToString()
                                          // Why are database IDs strings?
             )
        );
}
```

`viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus` appears to be a collection of strings; therefore, you're asking the database to convert `PaymentStatusId` to an nvarchar and do string comparisons with the elements of `SelectedPaymentStatus`. Yuck.

Since `viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus` is small, it might be better to create a temporary `List<int>` and use that in your query:

```
if (viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus != null) {

    // Let's do the conversion once, in C#
    List<int> statusIds = viewModel.SelectedPaymentStatus.Select( i => Convert.ToInt32(i) ).ToList();

    // Now select the matching orders
    queryOrder = queryOrder.Where(
                     m => statusIds.Contains(
                              m.Payments.Select(p => p.PaymentStatusId).Single())
                          )
                 );
}
```